# Need help > FirebasePushNotificationsPlugin : Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I use the [FirebasePushNotificationsPlugin](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin) in my Xamarin Forms project (4.7) to have the push notifications in my project.

I updated to the latest version (3.3.10) but now I get this error on Android (working on iOS):

```
**Java.Lang.IllegalStateException:** 'Default FirebaseApp is not initialized 
in this process com.companyname.firebasetest. 
Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.'
```

I found some solutions that does not work for me:

- My google-services.json has the GoogleServicesJson build action
- My firebase android app package name is the same package name on my Android project.
- I tried to update android's tools
- Also tried to add this line:

```
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Android.App.Application.Context);
```

PS:

- I created a new project (and new firebase project) but I get the same error
- I pulled the sample of the FirebasePushNotification Plugin, and still getting the error
- Notifications was working with version 2.3.x

What can I do ? I need help

Thx guys

Comment: Try to call `FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this,Intent);` in MainActivity. For more details of Android Initialization, you could check the link below. https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md#android-initialization

Comment: Hello, thanks you for your answer. I already called `FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this,Intent);` in MainActivity. I followed the documentation that you linked.

Could you pull the sample of the project and tell me if it works for you ?

Comment: I test the sample on the plugin link you provided without the "not initialized" exception. Have you check that?